# Dummy multiprocessing lock

Tags: python, sqlite, python-multiprocessing

I'm trying to diverse my huge for loop across multiple workers, but I've got this error: sqlite3.ProgrammingError: Recursive use of cursors not allowed.

I think I have to apply Lock. How can I do it?

```
import multiprocessing.dummy as multiprocessing

con = sqlite3.connect('db.db', check_same_thread=False)
cur = con.cursor()

def paramlist():
        for row in nodes.itertuples():
            l = []
            for row2 in ref_stops.itertuples():
                l.append((row[1], row[2], row[3], row2[1],
                         row2[2], row2[3], row2[4], haversine(row[3], row[2], row2[3], row2[2])))
            yield l

def func(params):
    # nodes_ref_stop = pd.DataFrame(params)
    cur.executemany('INSERT INTO stocks VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)', params)
    con.commit()

pool = multiprocessing.Pool()
pool.map(func, paramlist())
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot share cursors across different threads or processes. Each process must use its own cursor.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! But how can I workaround this problem? I tried to do itertools.cycle to iterate cursors for each process. But I've got the same error.